# Increase h2o.init timeout

Tags: r, h2o

How can I increase the h2o startup **timeout** when starting an h2o server via R?
I have a multinode AWS EC2 cluster, where I start a separate h2o server on each node. After startup, some EC2 nodes can be a bit slow and I'd rather increase the timeout than to re-run the `h2o` initialization code on these nodes.

What I am currently doing is along the lines of

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

workers=parallel::makePSOCKcluster(workerIPs,master=masterIP)
registerDoParallel(workers)

foreach(i=seq_along(workers),.inorder=FALSE,.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  library(h2o)
  h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
  paste0(capture.output(h2o.clusterStatus()),collapse="\n")
}
```

Slow nodes will throw an error at `h2o.clusterStatus()` if `h2o.init(nthreads=-1)` produced a timeout.

BTW: I am using h2o v 3.10.4.4 and I am on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Is your goal to have several H2O clusters running (one on each node)?  Or just a single H2O cluster across multiple nodes?  Usually we see people doing the latter (as outlined here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/ec2), so I am just curious.

Comment: Currently, I'd like to have one H2O cluster per node. I have implemented the CV and hyper parameter search algorithm myself -- so one h2o server per node works out best for me at the moment.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Could you just add a `Sys.sleep(10)` before your `h2o.init()` call to put some time between starting the worker node and launching the H2O cluster on it, or am I missing something here?

Comment: The workers have usually been started up a few minutes before. However, the initial EBS disk I/O of freshly created instances (from snapshots) can be very low for the first time a disk block is accessed. I guess that this is the reason why `h2o.init` fails sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I looked at the `h2o` source code on github and it does not seem as if there is a `timeout` argument (neither in `R` nor in the underlying `java` code). There is a `java` argument called `session_timeout` but I don't think this applies to my problem.

So what I did is this:

```
foreach(i=seq_along(workers),.inorder=FALSE,.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  library(h2o)
  startCounter=1
  startCounterMax=3
  while(inherits(clusterStatus<-try({
      h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
      capture.output(h2o.clusterStatus())
    },silent=TRUE),"try-error")&(startCounter<=startCounterMax)) {
    startCounter=startCounter+1
  }
  if (startCounter>startCounterMax) stop("Failed to start h2o server for ",
                                         startCounterMax," successive times")

  return(clusterStatus)
}
```

Not very nice but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to form a cluster of several H2O nodes (say cluster of 3 h2o nodes with one node per machine) and you want to wait for a specified time then you can try it in Java code - `water.H2O.waitForCloudSize(3, 50 * 1000/*ms*/);`
I assume there should be the corresponding parameter available in R as well.

Comment: I did not see this exposed via the `R` interface.