# Improve h2o DRF runtime on a multi-node cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, random-forest, h2o

I am currently running `h2o`'s DRF algorithm an a 3-node EC2 cluster (the h2o server spans across all 3 nodes).
My data set has 1m rows and 41 columns (40 predictors and 1 response).

I use the `R` bindings to control the cluster and the RF call is as follows

```
model=h2o.randomForest(x=x,
                       y=y,
                       ignore_const_cols=TRUE,
                       training_frame=train_data,
                       seed=1234,
                       mtries=7,
                       ntrees=2000,
                       max_depth=15,
                       min_rows=50,
                       stopping_rounds=3,
                       stopping_metric="MSE",
                       stopping_tolerance=2e-5)
```

For the 3-node cluster (c4.8xlarge, enhanced networking turned on), this takes about 240sec; the CPU utilization is between 10-20%; RAM utilization is between 20-30%; network transfer is between 10-50MByte/sec (in and out). 300 trees are built until early stopping kicks in.

On a *single-node* cluster, I can get the same results in about 80sec. So, instead of an expected 3-fold speed up, I get a 3-fold slow down for the 3-node cluster.

I did some research and found a few resources that were reporting the same issue (not as extreme as mine though). See, for instance:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/bnyhPyxftX8

Specifically, the author of http://datascience.la/benchmarking-random-forest-implementations/ notes that

> While not the focus of this study, there are signs that running the
>   distributed random forests implementations (e.g. H2O) on multiple
>   nodes does not provide the speed benefit one would hope for (because
>   of the high cost of shipping the histograms at each split over the
>   network).

Also https://www.slideshare.net/0xdata/rf-brighttalk points at 2 different DRF implementations, where one has a larger network overhead.

I think that I am running into the same problems as described in the links above.
How can I improve `h2o`'s DRF performance on a multi-node cluster?
Are there any settings that might improve runtime?
Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Random Forest is slower on a multi-node H2O cluster, it just means that your dataset is not big enough to take advantage of distributed computing.  There is an overhead to communicate between cluster nodes, so if you can train your model successfully on a single node, then using a single node will always be faster.

Multi-node is designed for when your data is too big to train on a single node.  Only then, will it be worth using multiple nodes.  Otherwise, you are just adding communication overhead for no reason and will see the type of slowdown that you observed.

If your data fits into memory on a single machine (and you can successfully train a model w/o running out of memory), the way to speed up your training is to switch to a machine with more cores.  You can also play around with certain parameter values which affect training speed to see if you can get a speed-up, but that usually comes at a cost in model performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I assume that other machine learning techniques (such as GBM, where the model size is generally smaller) do not run into this problem. It's a pity that DRF cannot be sped up, because depending on the problem size and DRF hyper parameters, single-node model training can take up to 45mins in my case. That makes sequential hyperparameter optimization tricky... Anyhow, I will try to run my code on a x1.32xlarge machine and see how it performs. From what I have seen, memory bandwidth seems to be the DRF bottleneck and these instance provide high mem bandwidth (supposedly).

Comment: GBMs will require a similar amount of memory -- usually you train fewer trees in an RF than GBM, but the trees are deeper in an RF.  Often GBM gets better performance than RF, so you might want to try out both to see what works best for your data.

Comment: Erin, one more question: Shouldn't it be possible to grow the individual trees of a forest independently from each other? Given that one turns off early stopping, there should be no intermediate communication overhead then. Very much like the proposed RF training algo #1 in Michal Malohlava's rf-brighttalk slides I have linked in my question. My guess is that for "big data" reasons h2o went for another implementation (that depends on intermediate exchange of histograms). Is there a plan at h2o to also implement algo #1 in addition to #2 (see slides)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it requires each of those independent processes to hold the entire training set in memory, so that's the big drawback.  We used to have both versions ("DRF" and "SpeeDRF") in H2O-2 but the latter is not scalable to big data.  It's possible that we could put a fast/smalldata version back in, but it's not on the roadmap at this time.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. BTW: Now with large memory cloud instances being available (2TB for AWS x1.32xlarge) and with Bayesian hyperparameter optimization becoming more popular, I would guess that user demand for the "small data" version will pick up.

Answer (score 1):

As Erin says, often adding more nodes just adds the capability for bigger data sets, not quicker learning. Random forest might be the worst; I get fairly good results with deep learning (e.g. 3x quicker with 4 nodes, 5-6x quicker with 8 nodes).

In your comment on Erin's answer you mention the real problem is you want to speed up hyper-parameter optimization? It is frustrating that `h2o.grid()` doesn't support building models in parallel, one on each node, when the data will fit in memory on each node. But you can do that yourself, with a bit of scripting: set up one h2o cluster on each node, do a grid search with a subset of hyper-parameters on each node, have them save the results and models to S3, then bring the results in and combine them at the end.  (If doing a random grid search, you can run exactly the same grid on each cluster, but it might be a good idea to explicitly use a different seed on each.)

Comment: Darren, thanks a lot for your input. What you describe (having a separate h2o cluster on each node) works very well for random search and grid search. Actually, I already use such a solution for grid/random search. However, if one wants to do Bayesian hyperparameter optimization (which, basically, works sequentially), it would be better to have several nodes work on one parameter configuration. BTW: I have your book ;)

Comment: Is your multinode grid/random search working for a set of H2O clusters? I'd love to see a blog post, or something, showing the scripts you use.  (Thanks for buying the book!)

Comment: I do everything from within R (on a master node that does not do any h2o calculations). The cluster setup is described in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515062/increase-h2o-init-timeout. But I am using `clusterCall` instead of `foreach` now for the cluster setup. The distribution of tasks is done via `foreach`. I do also split the tasks by CV-fold (not only by hyper param conf). The results are collected via `data.table::rbindList` (important if you have larger data sets).

Comment: Hi Darren, if you are still interested in running `R` ML tasks on a cluster, I can highly recommend the new `future` `R` package. I can now use my own load balancing methods, dynamically create/delete tasks and analyze incoming results sequentially. It does not solve the issue of getting Bayesian Optimization parallelized (as described in my original question) - but it's a much more flexible approach than using `foreach` or `clusterCall`.