# H2O AutoML building a large number of GBM models

Tags: h2o

I tried to use AutoML for a binary classification task with 100 hours. It appears that it is just building a large number of GBM models and not getting to other types. (So far built 40)

Is there a way to set the maximum number of GBM models?

Answer (score 4):

There is an order in which AutoML builds the models (the GBMs are first in line).  The length of the GBM model building process will depend on how much time you set for `max_runtime_secs`.  If you plan to run it for 100 hours, then a good portion of that will be spend in the GBM hyperparamter space, so I am not surprised that your first 40 models are GBMs.  In other words, this is expected behavior.

If you want variety in your models *as* they are training, then you can run a single AutoML job for a smaller `max_runtime_secs` (say 2 hours), and then run the AutoML process again on that same project (49 more times at 2 hours each -- or some combination that adds up to 100 hours).  If you use the same `project_name` when you start an AutoML job, a full new set of models (GBMs, RFs, DNNs, GLMs) should be added to the existing AutoML leaderboard.

Comment: 90 23:22:21.552 Info ModelTraining Built: 34 models for search: GBM hyperparameter search
91 23:24:34.304 Info ModelTraining GBM hyperparameter search complete
92 23:24:34.304 Info ModelTraining AutoML: out of time; skipping DL hyperparameter search
93 23:24:34.304 Info ModelTraining AutoML: out of time; skipping DL hyperparameter search

Comment: It looks like it does GBM hyperparameter search takes up the entire time and finishes before it gets to deep learning

Comment: It looks like it only ran for ~23.5 hours and not the full 100.  Did you stop it early or did it stop on it's own?

Comment: It stopped on its own, I will try to rerun it.

Comment: Please give it more memory if you can, it might have run out of RAM.

Comment: I just double checked the model, it definitely shows up as DONE.  
Run Time 558:10:56.131
Remaining Time 00:00:00.0
Type Auto Model
Key 
AutoML_20170719_181416
Description AutoML build
Status DONE
Progress 100%   Done.

Comment: The reason that it shows up as only 23 hours its because its over multiple days. .

Comment: 3 machines each have 256 gigs. Let me see what I can do. .

Comment: Ran the same dataset on 1 machine with a max time of 10 hours. Moved to DL hypersearch very quickly.

Comment: Did it complete the GBM grid before moving to DL grid?  Just checking -- you are using the 3.14.0.1 release?  Several important bug fixes went into AutoML in the 3.14.0.1 release.  If you can share your dataset, we can try to debug further (if so, create a JIRA ticket for the bug here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV)

Comment: I was using 3.12.01. Testing it on 3.14.01 now  `122 21:13:10.874 Info ModelTraining Built: 37 models for search: GBM hyperparameter search
123 21:13:12.147 Info ModelTraining GBM hyperparameter search complete
124 21:13:12.147 Info ModelTraining AutoML: out of time; skipping DL hyperparameter search
125 21:13:12.147 Info ModelTraining AutoML: out of time; skipping DL hyperparameter search`

Comment: I don't think it's the memory, the dataset is a binary classification with a size of 19mgs. Cluster is 4 machines with a 100gbs per box.

Comment: You definitely don't need 4 machines for such a small dataset (I assume you really mean 4 machines and not just 4 cores on a single machine).  I'd recommend re-starting the H2O cluster on a single machine and running it again, as it's wasting a lot of unnecessary time communicating between nodes when it doesn't need to be.  See more information about when to use a multi- vs single-machine cluster in H2O here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45496049/5451344

Answer (score 0):

As Erin said, if you run `AutoML` multiple times with the same `project_name` the results will accumulate into a single `leaderboard` and the hyperparameter searches will accumulate into the same `grid` objects.  However, `AutoML` will still run through the same sequence of model builds, so it will do a GBM hyperparameter search again before it gets to the `DL` model builds.

It feels like your GBM hyperparameter search isn't converging because the `stopping_tolerance` is too small for your dataset.  There was a bug in pre-release versions of the bindings which forced the stopping_tolerance to 0.001 instead of letting `AutoML` set it higher, if it calculated that that tolerance was too tight for a small dataset.  Which version of H2O-3 are you using?

A bit about stopping criteria:

The `stopping_criteria` such as `max_models`, `stopping_rounds`, and `stopping_tolerance` apply to the overall `AutoML` process as well as to the hyperparameter searches and the individual model builds.  At the beginning of the run `max_runtime_secs` is used to compute the end time for the entire process, and then at each stage the remaining overall time is computed and is passed down to the model build or hyperparameter search subtask.

The `Run Time   558:10:56.131` that you posted is really weird.  I don't see that sort of output in the `AutoML.java` code nor in the Python  or R bindings.  It looks at first glance like this is coming from outside of H2O. . .  Do you have any sense of what the real time was for this run?

We should be able to figure out what's going on if you do the following:

1. If you're not on the recent release version 3.14.x, please upgrade.
2. While we're debugging please set the `seed` parameter for your AutoML run so that we get repeatable results.
3. Please post your stopping criteria, your leaderboard output, your User Feedback output, and send your H2O logs to rpeck (at) h2o.ai and support (at) h2o.ai in case we need to delve further.  You can grab the H2O logs from the server or download them using Flow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just upgraded to 3.14.01. Will rerun the experiment and try to reproduce the results.

Comment: I am using auto stopping metric.    Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great!  I look forward to getting to the bottom of this!