# h2o autoML network usage

Tags: h2o

[image: windows screen shot]

First I would like to thank the H2o team for a great product and rapid development / iteration.

I was testing h2o autoML on a 4 machine cluster. (40 cores, 256 gigs of ram, gigabite bandwidth)

For a 20MB dataset I am noticing that the cluster is using up a lot of network and hardly touching the CPU. I was wondering if it makes sense for h2o to train 1 model per computer instead of trying to train every model on the entire cluster.

Answer (score 1):

AutoML is training H2O models in a sequence, so this advice applies to H2O models in general, not just AutoML -- if your dataset is small enough, adding machines to your H2O cluster will only slow down the training process.

> For a 20MB dataset I am noticing that the cluster is using up a lot of network and hardly touching the CPU.

If you have a 20MB dataset, it's always going to be better to run H2O on a single machine.  The overhead of using multiple machines is only worth it when your training frame won't fit into RAM on a single machine. 
 There is a longer explanation in another Stack Overflow answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45496049/5451344).

> I was wondering if it makes sense for h2o to train 1 model per computer instead of trying to train every model on the entire cluster.

It *does* make sense for small data, but H2O was designed to scale to big data (with millions or hundreds of millions of rows), so training several models in parallel is not the design pattern that was used.  To speed up the training process, you can use a single machine with more cores.